# Repository not found in Eclipse when tried to install Natural Plugin.. using win 11

Tags: eclipse-plugin

After Installing Eclipse and adding cucumber plugin, i tried installing Natural 0.9 and Testng plugin. but getting an error stating repository not found.

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: What repository does it say is not found?

Comment: Are you able to find it outside of Eclipse, or is it, in fact, actually gone?

Answer (score 2):

The [Natural Eclipse Marketplace entry](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/natural) seems to be outdated pointing to the HTTP instead of HTTP**S** update site `http://rlogiacco.github.com/Natural`.

As workaround go to ***Help > Install New Software...*** and **work with** the update site [**`https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural/`**](https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural/)

Comment: i tried with the above link it says "Could not find"

Comment: I tried the link just now and the httpS link works for me. Are you behind a proxy? Where does it say exactly "Could not find"? Could you please tell the exact error message?

Comment: Thank you so much guys it really helped me setting an environment