# Unable to install 'Natural' plugin to use Cucumber editor in eclipse through Help>Install New Software

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cucumber

Trying to Install 'Natural' plug-in through Eclipse:

> Help>Add New Software

Name:Natural
Location:http://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural

['Add New software' page screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc7mo.png)

However, I see the following error that Cucumber and JBehave Editor cannot be installed.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaF2s.png)

I'm using the following Eclipse version:

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
>
> Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
> Build id: 20211202-1639

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195203/6505250

Comment: Tried with https:/rlogiacco.github.io/Natural/ but I see 'cannot perform operation.Looking for alternate solutions' followed by cucumber Editor cannot be installed error.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Guys I also tried to Add the Natural Plugin for Eclipse IDE Version09/2022 - And even I was not able to get the same but I followed this path and the mentioned Website to Install the Natural Plugin.

- Click on Help in Eclipse Ide and Then click on Install New Software.
- Then Select on Work With and Mentioned this Website https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural.
- And then ADD the same Url you will Find Natural in the Drop down and then click on Next and Next . Restart the Eclipse you are Good to go with the Plugin.